# Omnibus test in generalized linear model in SPSS

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model

I am testing a few covariates in generalized linear model in SPSS. When the omnibus test comes out as non-significant, does that mean the model is not significant even if the my covariates came out as significant on the "test of model effects"?